# calculate the directional derivative in the direction of v at the given point

Tags: calculus

Calculate the directional derivative in the direction of v at the given point :

$$
\begin{cases}
f(x, y) = \tan^{-1}(xy) \\
   v = 1, 1, \,\, P = (7, 2)
\end{cases}
$$

This is what i have so far :

$$f_x=\frac 1 {(1+x^2)}\cdot xy \cdot y$$

$$f_y=\frac 1 {(1+x^2)} \cdot xy \cdot x$$

Comment: we would have to find the derivative with respect to x and y

Comment: thats pretty much all ive got

Comment: i dont know if i did it correctly

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is not correct. Note that
$$f_x=\frac{y}{1+x^2y^2},f_y=\frac{x}{1+x^2y^2}$$